# PHP printer_write PDF file?

Tags: php, pdf

I understand that you can use the printer_write function to print out text with PHP on a printer attached to the server. But can you use this function to print a pdf file that is located on the server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope.  There's free PDF libraries that can do this, such as mPDF and [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Comment: Hi again cale_b. I was planning on using FPDF to generate the pdfs. How would I go about using this to also print them out?

Comment: Ah.  Missed that detail.  That's a good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took alot of tinkering but I finally came up with:

```
exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 9.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe\" /t \"C:\\PathToPDF.pdf");
```

I couldn't get Foxit to use a smaller label size with the Brother printer, it would default to a 4x6" label and result in errors. (Using Brother QL-1060N). --Though, I must note that it would work fine with the default label size.

I got around this using Adobe Reader 9 and leaving it always open on the server computer, with appropriate print settings. I use 9 because for some reason Adobe Reader X, on every label after the first one, will be 1 ACSII character off. (EG. 1=2, 8=9,  =!).

Thanks Karl. I hope this is of great use to future readers! =)

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible but it's quite a hassle. We recently built an application that needed to print labels for customers from PHP. We decided to go with a Windows server and a printer that had its own software for printing.

This is the code we ended up with for printing the generated label:

```
system('"C:\Program Files\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe" /p "C:\www\pdf\label.pdf"');
```

Please note that this is a very specific solution for a specific printer and platform. Similar solutions for printers with proper Linux drivers or other printers for Windows should work fine providing they have a similar way of processing a file through the command line.

Comment: I was unaware of PHP's system function, truly amazing! This code should work perfectly as I am also running Windows. But is there a way to select a specific printer? I intend to use at least 2 different printers for 2 different things.

Comment: Since we use the specific Foxit executable as opposed to Windows built-in printing function I can't answer that question really. Which printer(s) are you using?

Comment: If it works I am more than willing to use Foxit. Printers: One of the printers is yet to be determined, the other is a Brother QL-1060N.  The unknown printer will be just a basic letter-size sheet printer of some sort.

Comment: I could take a closer look at our setup on monday when I'm at work if you're interested, I'm quite sure that we use a Brother printer in conjunction with Foxit.

Comment: I am definitely interested.

Comment: I'll comment here on monday and tell you the details then!

Comment: Okay! We use the Brother QL-700 and the Foxit software to print it. The Brother printer is set as the default printer but it should be possible to print with different printers by some command line parameters :)

Comment: Excellent! When I eventually figure that all out I'll make a note of it here. (Just finishing up on the design phase *sigh!*) Thanks for the help :)